# If statement runs but condition is not met

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, if-statement, passport.js

I'm using NodeJS, PassportJS, MySQL, and Sequalize(ORM for MySQL). This code is from my Passport.JS file. When a user registers on my website and the username or email is taken I will return an error. If both username and email can't be found in database a new create account will be created.

But the else statement to create a new account never runs. This error occurs when I create a new account with an untaken email and username.

Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
    at null. (/home/ubuntu/workspace/Authentication.1/config/passport/passport.js:59:21)
    at tryCatcher (/home/ubuntu/workspace/Authentication.1/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/ubuntu/workspace/Authentication.1/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/ubuntu/workspace/Authentication.1/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/ubuntu/workspace/Authentication.1/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/ubuntu/workspace/Authentication.1/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/home/ubuntu/workspace/Authentication.1/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/ubuntu/workspace/Authentication.1/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/Authentication.1/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:396:17)

```
// SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = username || email = ... 
User.findAll({
    where: {
      $or: [{username: username}, {email: req.body.email}]
    }
}).then(function(user){

// console.log('====================');
// console.log(user);
// console.log(user[0].username);  
// console.log(req.body.username);
// console.log(user[0].email);
// console.log(req.body.email);
// console.log('====================');

// If a user is returned from the database run this if statement
if(user != null) {
  // GETTING ERROR HERE. If username is already in database return err
  if(user[0].username == req.body.username) { **//THIS LINE CAUSE ERROR **
    console.log(user[0].username);  
    return done(null, false, console.log("USER TAKEN"),{message : 'That username is already taken'} );
  }

  // If email is already in database return err.
  else if(user[0].email == req.body.email) {
    return done(null, false, console.log("EMAIL TAKEN"),{message : 'That email is already taken'} );
  }  

}


else CREATE NEW ACCOUNT... // this never runs for some reason
```

> >
>   ENTIRE PASSPORT.JS FILE

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy(


  {           
    usernameField : 'username',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
  },


  function(req, username, password, done){
    var generateHash = function(password) {
      return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
    };

    User.findAll({
        where: {
          $or: [{username: username}, {email: req.body.email}]
        }
    }).then(function(user){

    // console.log('====================');
    // console.log(user);
    // console.log(user[0].username);  
    // console.log(req.body.username);
    // console.log(user[0].email);
    // console.log(req.body.email);
    // console.log('====================');


    if(user != null) {
      if(user[0].username == req.body.username) {
        console.log(user[0].username);  
        return done(null, false, console.log("USER TAKEN"),{message : 'That username is already taken'} );
      }


      else if(user[0].email == req.body.email) {
        return done(null, false, console.log("EMAIL TAKEN"),{message : 'That email is already taken'} );
      }  

    }


    else
    {
      var userPassword = generateHash(password);
      var data =
      { 
        username: username,
        password: userPassword,
        email: req.body.email
      };
```

Comment: In the `findAll` you're using `username`, why did it suddenly change to `req.body.username`, and have you included a bodyparser ?

Comment: are you 100% certain that `user` is an array and that it have at least 1 element? Maybe `findAll` returns an empty array instead of null

Comment: @adeneo Because PassportJS only allows a username and passport field. I'm creating an email field by myself so I have to use req.body.username.

 Yes I'm sure that it is an array.

Comment: `[] !== null` returns `true`. So if your query returns empty array, if statement will still be `true` and accessing `0` element of empty array is `undefined`. Hence the error `Cannot read property 'username' of undefined ` .. .are you sure your response is not empty?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. By Stack Overflow policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please take a look at 
[**How does deleting work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

user is an array if you use user[0]

The condition is therefor :

```
if(user != null && user.length > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're checking on either user[0].username or req.body.username in a case when it doesn't exist. If that is the case, you can add an additional check in your if statement to ensure that you do not check for username in cases where the higher tier key doesn't exist like:

```
if (user[0] && req.body && (user[0].username == req.body.username)) {
      // your code here 
   }
```

I would check the line that the error is referencing to determine whether it is the user or the body that has an undefined username. Otherwise, as adeneo mentioned, it is possible that you are not running body-parser.